# Linq to entities : Stored procedure + set navigation properties

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I set an object entity with a stored procedure, but the navigation properties are always equals at null ...

The aim is to include or join an external entity.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to "load" your navigation properties before accessing them.
If the navigation is a collection, use

```
yourNavigationPropertyName.Load();
```

if it's a single object, use the reference property associated :

```
yourNavigationPropertyNameReference.Load();
```

Later in your development, you should meet an usual related problem. I suggest you to take a look on this post, which deals with entity framework lazy loading :

[ADO.NET Entity Framework IsLoaded and Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710731/ado-net-entity-framework-isloaded-and-load/2239967#2239967)

Comment: It's a single object, I will use the reference property associated, thanks.

My issue is all foreign keys (navigation properties) are null when I set the object entity with the stored procedure, so I can't make a "load".

I don't know why ...

My Code :

var sp = context.GetUserEntityTransactions(SesameId);
List<Transaction> transations = new List<Transaction>(sp.ToList());

The transations foreign keys are null

Comment: What about trying 

sp.Load();

List transations = new List(sp.ToList());

?

Answer (score 0):

It's a single object, I will use the reference property associated, thanks. My issue is all foreign keys (navigation properties) are null when I set the object entity with the stored procedure, so I can't make a "load". I don't know why ...

My Code :

```
var sp = context.GetUserEntityTransactions(SesameId);
```

List transations = new List(sp.ToList());

The transations foreign keys are null